# Extract .tar.xz with pv progress bar

Tags: tar, pv

I have a problem with extracting files with a progress bar. It always gives me an error:

```sh
pv "file.tar.xz" | tar -xf

tar: need argument -- f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-f` option requires the archive to operate on as an argument, see [man tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).
Use `-` to extract from `stdin` (provided by the pipe `pv "file.tar.xz" |` in your case):

```
pv "file.tar.xz" | tar -xJf-
```

As `-` is usually the compiled-in default archive (you can probably check with `tar --show-defaults`), you might be able to omit the `-f` option altogether and simply use

```
pv "file.tar.xz" | tar -xJ
```

Comment: This work: `pv "file.tar.xz" | tar -xJ` thinks like `-xf-` or `-x` do not work

Comment: Right: When extracting from a pipe, `tar` isn't able to infer the compression program from an archive suffix. I'll edit the answer; thanks!

Comment: I get `xz: (stdin): File format not recognized` with either of these options.

Answer (score 4):

this work for me: `pv "file.tar.gz" | tar -xzf - -C target_directory`